# Background image URL cannot find the path on localhost

Tags: html, css

I have an image located in the assets folder within the root directory. Within the assets folder, I have the img folder and in that I have the image in question. My `scss` folder is also in my root which houses my `style.css` and my `style.scss`.  I have tried a variety of ways to get the image to appear but have already spent an hour trying to figure this out.

In my html, I have:

```
<div class="popUpMain">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="image-area">
            <div class="close-button">&times;</div>
              <div class="img"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

and my css for these elements are as follows:

```
.popUpMain {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1099;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.popUpMain.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popUpMain .box {
  // width: 750px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.popUpMain.show .box {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.popUpMain .box .image-area {
  position: relative;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 1px 19px 10px 19px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popUpMain .box .image-area .img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(../assets/img/mesa-de-trabajo.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I am sure it is something simple that I am missing but for the life of my, I cannot see the forest through the tree. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: The reason I have some hidden properties is in my javascript call here:

```
const popUpControl = document.querySelector('.popUpMain');
const close = document.querySelector('.close-button');

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    showPopup();
});

function showPopup () {
    const timeLimit = 2; // seconds
    let i = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(function() {
        i++;
        if(i == timeLimit) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            popUpControl.classList.add("show");
        }
        console.log(i); 
    }, 1000);
}

close.addEventListener("click", function() {
    popUpControl.classList.remove("show");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *both* your stylesheet and image location. Your syntax is correct, but you need to remember you're calling the image from the *stylesheet* location.

Example:

```
Root
 - css
   - styles.css
 - assets
   - img
     - yourImage.jpg
```

In this case, in your stylesheet you would write

```
background: url(../assets/img/yourImage.jpg);
```

Take a look at your stylesheet location and adjust!

Comment: Thank you @Leez0r for your answer. Does it make a difference if I am using scss and it compiles down to my style.css which is in my scss folder(in root).??? Thanks.

Comment: @ErikJamesRobles The image is being called from whatever stylesheet is being served. So if your style.css file is the stylesheet being loaded then that's where you need to be referencing from.

Answer (score 1):

**Issues:**

1. `.popUpMain .box .image-area .img` - Here you are calling .img class, in HTML, you have written "image" class. So, fix this.
2. Remove `opacity:0` from `.popUpMain .box`
3. Remove   `visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;` from `.popUpMain`

```css
.popUpMain {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1099;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.popUpMain.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popUpMain .box {
  // width: 750px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.popUpMain.show .box {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.popUpMain .box .image-area {
  position: relative;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 1px 19px 10px 19px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popUpMain .box .image-area .image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popUpMain">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="image-area">
            <div class="close-button">&times;</div>
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```